# Кеширование

Tags: кэширование

Всем привет, вот настало время изучать кеширование, я прочитал статей по кешированию, посмотрел примеры, и т.д. И возникло несколько вопросов...

1) В статьях пишут, что кешировать для максимальной скорости нужно **ВСЁ**, и тут-же возникает вопрос, вот допустим у меня в проекте есть стена(к примеру vk.com или facebook), там люди оставляют записи, НО если я закешировал эту часть сайта, и кеш обновляется каждые 60 сек, то получается, что человек написал сообщение, а оно появилось только через 60 сек?

2)Кеширование, это можно сказать что сохранение данных из БД в файл? Так? Или я что-то просто не дочитал...  Если кешировать ВСЁ, то разве скорость которую мы выиграли за счет уменьшения запросов к БД, мы уменьшили скорость, потому что за информацией скрипт обращается к файлу(скорость передачи данных с жесткого диска), или я опять что-то не понял?

3)Что нужно кешировать, а что нет? Потому что, если верить некоторым статьям которые говорят что надо сделать как в пункте №1, то опять-же как показывать пользователю обновлённую информацию?

Comment: >НО если я закешировал эту часть сайта, и кеш обновляется каждые 60 сек, то получается, что человек написал сообщение, а оно появилось только через 60 сек?

Не, можно круче: при новой записи кэш тупо сбрасывается и сразу же (или при первом запросе, но лучше сразу же) воссоздается. Что здесь сразу надо учитывать - это dogpile-эффект, нужно предупредить ситуацию, когда несколько запросов разом захотят ребилдить кэш. В этом случае один должен ребилдить, остальные - ожидать.

Comment: При некоторых способах использования (правда, не очень эффективных) можно упорядочивать кэш по временной метке и создавать новый при обновлении источника, не затрагивая старый. В этом случае dogpile-эффекта не будет, но будут затраты на поиск кэша, что немного противоречит самой идее кэширования (обычно запрос в кэш точно знает где лежат данные и не теряет времени на их поиск).

Comment: >2...
Здесь два пункта: во-первых, за счет  кэширования в файл можно легко выиграть. Вы собираете сложный объект с кучей связей из семидесяти таблиц и кладете в файл в json-формате - и выигрываете солидное количество времени.
Во-вторых, кэш редко хранится в файлах, разве что промежуточное состояние, которое вроде бы и не постоянные данные, но и считаться при каждом запросе не должно. Нормальный кэш располагается прямо в оперативке, и его скорость во много раз выше. Оттуда и серваки с 400 гб оперативы.

Comment: А можно название такого кэша, который в оперативке всё держит(использую Yii). Я просто в основном FileCache использовал.

Comment: Я в этом так и не копался, но, насколько понимаю, по этому принципу работают практически все хранилища. Memcached, например, должен так делать, redis по идее тоже, но из краткого описания не понял, как именно он хранит информацию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попытаюсь кратко:

1) Да. Если грубо не конкретизируя саму процедуру кеширования.

2) Нет. Кешировать можно не обязательно в файл, можно кешировать в абстракции языка (в объекты) они будут доступны быстрее потому что уже в оперативной памяти.

Кешируют кстати не только данные БД, но и например результаты работы какого-нибудь алгоритма (если частенько возникает задачка то в первый раз мы её решаем, а во второй уже берём из кеша)

3) Если логика не подразумевает именно такой политики предоставления информации, тогда кешировать ненужно. Или ещё вариант, пусть при добавлении записи именно эта информация сбрасывается в кеше и всё в порядке и тогда при следующем обращении к стене всё подтянется т.к. в кеше не нашлось.

В кешировании нет тайн, это просто метод работы с данными.

Comment: Или ещё вариант, пусть при добавлении записи именно эта информация сбрасывается в кеше

Это хорошо, но она ведь сбрасывается, только у этого пользователя кто её добавил, а не у всех, друг другие пользователи зайдут на стену, она-же ничего не увидят(

Comment: @Angus123
Почему? Кэш хранится на сервере, а не у пользователя. Когда страница загружается, сервер смотрит наличие кэша и загружает его. Таким образом кэш един для всех.

Comment: @Fike Спасибо, не знал... Ну тогда уже вопросов нету :)

Comment: @Fike, @Angus123, смотря где кеширование происходит.

Можно кэшировать на клиенте, например мы не обновляем страницу (через submit формы), а  дёргаем методы через AJAX (сейчас это вообще очень частый случай), тогда вполне можно хранить кэшь в переменных JavaScript (или даже с обновлениями в LocalStore или SessionStore) для клиента.

Но в примере со стеной, конечно я имел введу кэш сервера.

К стати можно ещё для клиента в сессии что-то кэшировать, например, права доступа, тогда для вступления новых прав в силу потребуется перелогиниться.

Comment: Про клиентское кэширование очень не плохая [лекция][1] у yandex'а

[1]: http://tech.yandex.ru/education/shri/msk-2012/talks/539/